# Complext Object Conditional Mapping in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

**It is my destination object and nested object** :

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategorryDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**It is my source object and nested object** :

```cs
public class CategoryUpdateDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategorryDescription { get; set; }
    public List<ProductUpdateDTO> ProductList { get; set; }
}

public class ProductUpdateDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**It is My MapProfile**

```cs
public MapProfile()
{

    CreateMap<Category, CategoryCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<Product, ProductCreateDTO>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<Category, CategoryUpdateDTO>();
    CreateMap<CategoryUpdateDTO, Category>();
    CreateMap<Product, ProductUpdateDTO>();
    CreateMap<ProductUpdateDTO, Product>();
    CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>().ReverseMap();
}
```

**It is my service code**

```cs
var category = await _myContext.Categories.Include(x => x.ProductList).Where(x => x.Id == categoryUpdateDTO.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

category = _mapper.Map<CategoryUpdateDTO, Category>(categoryUpdateDTO, category);
```

**My Question**

While doing this matching, what should I do to match the ProductUpdate list and the Pruduct list with the same Id columns?
**Not**
I want to do this because
I want the entity state to be tracked accurately by the change tracker.

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.